# Cauchy–Kowalevski Theorem for PDEs

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

I hope to extend the PDEs across the boundary using Cauchy–Kowalevski Theorem.

Given a real analytic manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, the solution $u$ to the PDE $$\triangle u+b(x)\nabla u+c(x)u=0$$ on $M$, $\triangle$ is the Laplace Operator on the manifold $M$. It satisfies Neumann boundary condition $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$. While the analytic funtions $b(x)$, $c(x)$ depends on the distance function to $\partial M$ when close to boundary. I know I can embed $M\subset M_1$ which is open real analytic manifold.

I am wondering if I can  extend the solutions to a neighborhood of $\partial M$.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is $u|_{\partial M}$?

Comment: Do not know! It can be some analytic function. I do not need the uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: If it is analytic, then it is a straightforward application.

Comment: Thanks! Is it OK? even if $b(x)$ $c(x)$ may depend on distance function to the boundary.

Comment: Are you wanting something like Schwarz principle? It seems like a direct application of CK Theorem from your description?

Comment: It is OK, as long as b and c are analytic.

Comment: No. I do not need Schwartz principle. Thanks @ Henry, L
If I do not know  any boundary conditions for the elliptic equations described above, I can also extend the solutions across the $\partial M$, right?

Comment: You probably need to know that the coefficients (and the metric) can be in some sense extended across the boundary. In this case the application is straightforward. Otherwise some singularity may occur at the boundary

Comment: Thanks Fan and Piero for the answers. For example, if $b(x)=\nabla d(x)$, $c(x)=|\nabla d(x)|^2-\triangle d(x)$, where $d(x)$ is the distance function to the boundary $\partial M$ under the  metric of $M_1$, Can $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ be analytically extended across $\partial M$?

Comment: For your specific $b(x)$ and $c(x)$, you only need to know: signed distance to the boundary is smooth, if there are no corners, and real analytic if there are no corners.